# Create new variables within loop in Stata

Tags: stata

I am currently trying to create a loop to deseasonalize several hundred time series which consist of search queries, economic-related words taken from dictionaries. The (working) command my deseasonalization is based on looks like this

```
sum ACCRUE, meanonly
local mACCRUE =r(mean)
reg ACCRUE January  February March April May June July August September October November December, nocons
predict double ACCRUESA, residual
replace ACCRUESA=ACCRUESA+`mACCRUE'
```

So in the the end I created a new deseasonalized time series called ACCRUESA from the base time series ACCRUE.

In the next step I want to automatize the command for the rest of the queries. I tried the following

```
foreach var of varlist a-z {
sum `var', meanonly
local mu =r(mean)
reg `var' January  February March April May June July August September October November December, nocons
predict double `var'SA, residual
replace `var'SA=`var'SA+`mu'
 }
```

I use a-z to loop through the queries, but maybe this is the wrong approach. My goal was to exclude the monthly dummies. Anyway, after excecuting I get an error that a variable is unknown. You will observe that I tried to create a new variable using the `var' and a suffix, but I am not sure if this approach is feasible.

Does someone have an idea how to improve my command?

Comment: "that is probably the cause for the mistake": I don't think you have grounds for saying that. The key to this is where in the loop the error occurs. Also, whether "several hundred time series" really corresponds to a varlist `a-z`. What do you get with `ds a-z`?

Comment: I agree with @NickCox. My hunch is that you want to refer to all variables in your database. Instead of `a-z`, use `_all` or `*`. Alternatively, spell out the variables explicitly.

Comment: `_all` would include `January` to `December`, not what is wanted here.  The other obvious check is that `January` to `December` do exist exactly as you spelled the names.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering everyone. Indeed, as Nick pointed out I did not use _all as I do not want to include the monthly dummies. And for explicitly naming the variables there are too many of them. Using _a-z was more of a guess as I saw something similar in a textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the variable list you give for the loop: `a-z`. I initially suggested you use `_all`, instead.
@NickCox correctly pointed out that `_all` would include undesired variables in the `<varlist>` (i.e. the months). You can remove those from the `<varlist>`. Below an example.

```
clear all
set more off

*------------------- Create example data -----------------------

sysuse auto

foreach var in `=c(Months)' {
    gen `var' = 0
}

*------------------ Remove some variables ----------------------

* All variables
ds
local allvars = r(varlist)
display "`allvars'"

* Strings to remove
local removethis = c(Months)

* modified local (no months)
local myvars: list allvars - removethis
display "`myvars'"

*-------------------------- Process ----------------------------

foreach var of varlist `myvars' {
    display "`var'"
    sum `var', meanonly
    display r(mean)
}
```

This involves using *macro lists*. Type `help macrolists` for details.

Comment: Roberto, thanks for your input. I edited my post to make it clearer. I need to have the search queries (=the time series) to be the varlist and thus exclude the other variables, e.g. the monthly dummies. I will try your approach and see what it does. Thanks again!

Comment: I've posted one way of excluding the 'month' variables.

Comment: To confirm: The varlist `a-z` was identified as a guess and indeed it is essentially certain to be what is crashing your code. You need a way of telling Stata what the variables are. @Roberto has given you some technique. If it is not enough, you must tell us much more about the naming conventions used in your dataset.

Comment: Yes I can confirm, varlist a-z was the problem, the rest of the code is fine. 
Robertos code does not seem to work as it apparently tries to generate variables for the respective month, but these are already created. 
To give you a better understanding of my data, I have columns with dates (daily), returns, months (derived from the dates), all twelve months as dummy variables (dependend on month) and the queries.

Comment: Maybe it is more easier to tell Stata what specifically should not be in the varlist, so just substracting the returns, the months and the dummies. Ill check.

Comment: That's precisely what I do with that code. I generate variables in order to create an **example database** I can work with.  That part of the code is not supposed to serve you any good,  except to show that the _other_ parts of the code work.

Comment: You are telling us essentially nothing about the structure of variable names, just what they are.

Comment: This is still unanswerable in a way that really benefits anyone.